# WKWebView iOS 16 Web Share API on file: protocol

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am attempting to use `navigator.share` in a file running in WKWebView on iOS 16. The file is loaded into the web view using a `file:` protocol path like so:

```swift
uiView.loadFileURL(Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "web")!, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

I have this setting on:

```swift
configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
```

So I am able to load `file:` protocol files into the web view, but I don't seem to be able to use the Web Share API. I get this error:

> NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

However, when I point the web view at this HTTPS URL, it works:

https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-share

This leads me to believe the Web Share API is not working because the HTML file loaded over the `file:` protocol is not viewed as secure and thus the JavaScript runtime don't treat the code on it as if it was running in a secure context.

As a result, I believe the access to the `navigator.share` API is forbidden.

Is there a way to configure `WKWebView` to allow access to secure context JS/DOM/web APIs without using a custom scheme (and adding an extra layer atop just loading my file from the bundle)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the `file:` protocol or secure context.

I looked through WebKit source code for `navigator.share` and found that `NotAllowedError` gets returned whenever there don't seem to be conditions met for transient activation.

https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/d9bcb08521ddb86af9a713213d15488712919143/Source/WebCore/page/Navigator.cpp#L172

```cpp
void Navigator::share(Document& document, const ShareData& data, Ref<DeferredPromise>&& promise)
{
    if (!document.isFullyActive()) {
        promise->reject(InvalidStateError);
        return;
    }

    if (!validateWebSharePolicy(document)) {
        promise->reject(NotAllowedError, "Third-party iframes are not allowed to call share() unless explicitly allowed via Feature-Policy (web-share)"_s);
        return;
    }

    if (m_hasPendingShare) {
        promise->reject(InvalidStateError, "share() is already in progress"_s);
        return;
    }

    auto* window = this->window();
    if (!window || !window->consumeTransientActivation()) {
        promise->reject(NotAllowedError);
        return;
    }

    if (!canShare(document, data)) {
        promise->reject(TypeError);
        return;
    }
```

Transient activation is the thing where some web APIs will only run in response to a user gesture; the user gesture is either a part of the call stack leading up to the API call invocation or a user gesture has happened recently.

More about transient activation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transient_activation

In my case I did have a user gesture there but also a WebRTC peer connection ICE gathering flow which while seemingly quick I guess lasted too long and it reset the transient activation flag preventing me from using the Web Share API at the end of the ICE gathering phase.

The fix is to prepare whatever you need for the Web Share API data payload in advance and in response to the user gesture, such as a button click, call the web API straight away.